# save active <li> when page reload

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I have this simple css menu, It works fine, but when the page is reloaded the li class="active" reset.

```
     <ul>
             <li class="active"><a href="/">Page2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Page2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li ><a href="Page3.html">Page3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="page4.html">page 4</a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

How can I save li class="active" when the page is reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Please save active `li` in `cookie` and when reload page get last saved active `li` and set active class